# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: spring-boot

```
 when i am trying to get values by id ..i got error like this in postman
```

{
        "timestamp": 1547708533031,
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error", 
        "exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
        "message": "Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.Cetegory.Entites.ArtistRegister[\"subcetgory\"]->com.Cetegory.Entites.SubCetegory_$$_jvst706_1[\"handler\"])",
        "path": "/getartist/2"
    }

```
this is contoller for get data by id
@RestController
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    ArtistService artser;

    @PostMapping(value="/addArtist",produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody public ArtistRegister addArtist(@RequestBody ArtistRegister artist) {

        ArtistRegister artRegister = null;
        try {

            artRegister = artser.addArtist(artist);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return artRegister;

    }  

    @RequestMapping(value="/getartist/{artist_id}",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody   public ArtistRegister getArtistDetails(@PathVariable ("artist_id") int artist_id ,HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    return artser.getArtistDetails(artist_id);

    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{artist_id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE,produces="application/json")
        public void deleteById(@PathVariable (value="artist_id") int artist_id,HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
            artser.deleteById(artist_id);
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateartist", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    public ArtistRegister updateArtist(@RequestBody ArtistRegister artreg, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception 
    {   
        return artser.updateArtist(artreg);
    }


this is service
@Service
@Transactional
public class ArtistService {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository artrep;

    @Autowired
    private RegisterDAO artdao;

    public ArtistRegister addArtist(ArtistRegister artreg) {

        ArtistRegister artReg = null;
        try {
            artReg = artrep.save(artreg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return artReg;
    }

    public ArtistRegister getArtistDetails(int artist_id) {
        return artdao.getArtistDetails(artist_id);

    }

    public void deleteById(int artist_id) {
        artdao.deleteById(artist_id);
    }

    public ArtistRegister updateArtist(ArtistRegister artreg) {
        return artdao.updateArtist(artreg);

    }

}


this is DAO
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RegisterDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SubCetegoryDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entitymanager;

    public ArtistRegister getArtistDetails(int artist_id) {

        try 
        {
            String hql = "FROM ArtistRegister a where a.artist_id=?";
            return (ArtistRegister) entitymanager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(1, artist_id).getSingleResult();
        } 
        catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) 
        {
            return null;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            logger.error("Exception in getUser"+ e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@JsonManagedReference` annotation and update fetch type to LAZY, by following way:

```
 @OneToOne(targetEntity = SubCetegory.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "sub_cetegory_id")
```

What are fetch types Lazy and Eager?

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed.

**REFERENCES**

[Official documentation fetch type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html)

Comment: Did it work? If this answer helps you please mark it as answer. Thanks. @divyau